# rMATS error "unable to access a shared library"

Tags: centos, conda, blas, openblas, rna-seq

I am trying to run rMATS on a Linux (CentOS) cluster.  On this system I do not have root access. I installed several of the rMATS dependency packages using the  anaconda `conda install` package manager.

rMATS is unable to access a shared library `libblas.so.3` on the system and throws an error `rMATSexe: error while loading shared libraries: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Although I have located the `libblas.so.3` library on my system `/Users/paul/anaconda3/pkgs/lapack-3.6.1-1/lib/libblas.so.3` I am unsure how to make it accessible to the rMATS software as a "shared library".

I have tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ranum/anaconda3/pkgs/lapack-3.6.1-1/lib/libblas.so.3` but this did not work.

Where can i put this libblas.so.3 library so that it can be found by the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a directory path not a file path. You want to set it like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/ranum/anaconda3/pkgs/lapack-3.6.1-1/lib
```